# Unable to add values to array state React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, websocket

I recently posted a question with regards to sending and receiving data via a websocket. In the interest of not duplicating most of the work, the original question is found here: [Socket.io emitting undefined variable React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414468/socket-io-emitting-undefined-variable-react)

I have since modified my app slightly so that each id received from the server gets added or removed to a `disabled` array (if the `focus` parameter received from the server is true, add the id and if not, remove it). This is so that I can disabled/enable questions based off the focus sent.

The slight adjustments I've made are three fold, all within the `App.js` file

**1. Add `disabled` array to state**

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState([])
```

**2. Include `disabled` parameter to the question**

```
<TextArea
    cols={50}
    helperText="Optional helper text here; if message is more than one line text should wrap (~100 character count maximum)"
    id="text2"
    invalidText="Invalid error message."
    labelText="Text area label"
    placeholder="Placeholder text"
    rows={4}
    onFocus={() => setFocusTrue('text2')}
    onBlur={() => setFocusFalse('text2')}
    disabled={disabled.indexOf('text2')!==-1}
/>
```

You will note in the above that the `disabled` parameter will be set to true if the questionId is included in the `disabled` array (therefore disabling the question) and false if not

**3. Add questionId to `disabled` state array**

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message", ({ user, id, focus }) => {
        console.log(user, "clicked on", id, "with focus", focus)
        console.log('adding', id, 'to disabled')
        setDisabled(prevDisabled => [...prevDisabled, id]);
        console.log("disabled:", disabled)
    })
}, [])
```

For now, I am just adding all the questionIds coming from the server to the `disabled` array so I can test whether they are indeed getting added. But this is my issue in that the `disabled` array is always empty (see screenshot below). The `id` variable exists as can be seen in the console log output that precedes setting the new `disabled` state, but it is not getting added as expected.

[image]

**EDIT:**
As per the comments, I can see that the `disabled` array is in fact getting updated, if I `console.log(disabled)` just before rendering. However, if I apply any sort of logic to the array, I get an error. The below is the modified `useEffect` which contains some logic (essentially, to add or remove an id to the array)

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message", ({ user, id, focus }) => {
      console.log(user, "clicked on", id, "with focus", focus)
      console.log('adding', id, 'to disabled')
      if (focus) {
        console.log('not my user and focus is true')
        setDisabled(prevDisabled => [...prevDisabled, id])
        console.log("disabled after adding", disabled)
      } else {
        let filteredArray = disabled.filter(idToRemove => idToRemove !== id)
        setDisabled({disabled: filteredArray});
      }
      console.log("disabled:", disabled)
    })
  }, [])
```

When I click on a textbox, the `id` of the question gets added to the `disabled` array as expected, but when I click out of it, I get the following error:

> disabled.indexOf is not a function

This referring to `disabled={disabled.indexOf('text1')!==-1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is fine, if you are trying to console.log the most resent state right after you setting it, it won't work why? setState is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) it might not work real time as you expected.

what you actually want to try is add a useEffect and listen for changes of the `disabled` state

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("disabled", disabled);
}, [disabled]); // since disabled is in the dependency array this hook function will call, every time when the disabled gets updated.
// so you are so sure the disabled is getting updated correctly
```

or just do a simple `console.log(disabled)` right before the render and see.

and your modified version of `useEffect` is incorrect as I see, it should be corrected as

```
....
const filteredArray = disabled.filter(idToRemove => idToRemove !== id)
setDisabled(filteredArray);
....
```

Comment: So would I in essence have two different useEffect functions, one that specifically checks for changes in the disabled state as you've mentioned but the other that waits for messages from the websocket?

Comment: You don't have to  use a `useEffect` just to listen for it's changing

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand. What would the `useEffect` look like in that case given the `socket.on` part? You are correct in that if I `console.log(disabled` right before the render, I can see that the Ids are indeed included

Comment: Aha, if you see the `disabled` in the console.log your code is working fine (disabled is updating correctly and nothing needs to be changed), the `useEffect` that i have told you put, is just to verify `disabled` is getting updated correctly (because you had a confusion of it's not getting updated and every time its empty?)

Comment: Ok great, that makes sense. But if I wanted to add logic to the `disabled` array, where can I do that? It seems as though `disabled` is getting updated as you've said, but whenever I apply any logic, it errors. I've edited my question to demonstrate an example.

Comment: I think `setDisabled({disabled: filteredArray});` is wrong it should be `setDisabled(filteredArray);`